# How to hit api with jwt headers on onclick method?

Tags: java, android, api, android-volley

devs hope all are fine and shine I am stuck into a problem of hitting the URL of my API from onclick method. I want to send the JWT token in the header and the value of my id on the click of the layout. API accept header and id argument. I am unable to do this as I am very new to the programming world any help from you people must be most appreciated thanks:
Below my function code :

```js
profile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                String str = taginput.getText().toString();
                tag_id = taginput.getText().toString();
                    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
          //I want to send these two things to the next activity JWT to haders and id to hit api   
                    token = session.getStringData("jwtToken");
                    id = session.getStringData("mtagid");
                if(!str.isEmpty()) {
                
                    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
                    token = session.getStringData("jwtToken");
                    tag_id = session.getStringData("tagid");

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CInfo.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please Enter CNIC first!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }

            }
        });
```

The class where API call and all the functionality is written is given below :

```js
public class CInfo extends AppCompatActivity {
    private String TAG = CInfo.class.getSimpleName();
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private static final int MY_SOCKET_TIMEOUT_MS = 50000;
    ListView listView;
    List<ConstantClass> constantClassList;

    ProgressBar progressBar;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private SessionManager session;
    String token;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_c_info);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        progressBar=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progress);
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        constantClassList=new ArrayList<>();

        sendAndRequestResponse();

        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
        token = session.getStringData("jwtToken");

    }

    private void sendAndRequestResponse() {



        mRequestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest ( Request.Method.POST, AppConfig.URL_CARS_INFO+DemoClass.tag_id, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject> () {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {


                try {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray ( "result" );


                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length (); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject ( i );

                        String ownername = jsonObject.getString ( "ownername" );

                        String tokenno = jsonObject.getString ( "tokenno" );
                        String registration = jsonObject.getString ( "registration" );
                        String cnic = jsonObject.getString("cnic");
                        String balance = jsonObject.getString("balance");
                        String veh_type = jsonObject.getString("veh_type");

                        ConstantClass constantClass=new ConstantClass(ownername,tokenno,registration,cnic,balance,veh_type);
                        constantClassList.add(constantClass);


                    }
                    CustomAdapter customAdapter=new CustomAdapter(CInfo.this,constantClassList);
                    listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace ();


                }


            }

        }, new Response.ErrorListener () {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                if (error.networkResponse == null) {
                    if (error.getClass().equals(TimeoutError.class)) {
                        // Show timeout error message
                        Toast.makeText(CInfo.this,
                                "Oops. Timeout error!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }

            }


        }

        )
        {



            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                // Posting parameters to login url
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("tagid", DemoClass.mtag_id);
                //params.put("password", password);

                return params;
            }


            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

                params.put("Authorization", token);
                Log.d(TAG,"Tokkenn0"+token);
                return params;
            }

        };


        mRequestQueue.addRequestFinishedListener(new RequestQueue.RequestFinishedListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onRequestFinished(Request<String> request) {

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);


            }

        });
        mRequestQueue.add (jsonObjectRequest);
        jsonObjectRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                MY_SOCKET_TIMEOUT_MS,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

        //mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue ( CInfo.this );





    }
}
```

Comment: If you need to call some API via android I suggest you to use some library (eg RETROFIT) that do the dirty work and allow you to set up only what you need.

Comment: You seem to have `getHeaders` overriden, so whats the error/problem?

Comment: Problem is when i click on profile which has onclick it doesn't hit the api my data is not displayed in cinfo activity and logcat has no error

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is here:

```
sendAndRequestResponse();
session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
token = session.getStringData("jwtToken");
```

It should be:

```
session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
token = session.getStringData("jwtToken");
sendAndRequestResponse();
```

Or else you will only set the `token` which is needed in `sendAndRequestResponse()` after calling the method which is then too late.

Also ensure you have this permission declared in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Activity i want to send token in header and id in params right now when i click on profile it didn't hit url of my api and logcat didn't show any error i log the token in cinfo activity logcat only display that token but api is not hit i m really confused and frustrated by this problem

Comment: Postman shows data when i give token in header and pass id in form data

Comment: Did you try what I suggested? Also have you got this in your manifest `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`?

Comment: Also in your `onErrorResponse` comment out all the code and put a `Log.d` statement for now until you get it working. Does any breakpoint inside `onReponse` or `onErrorRepsonse` ever hit?

Comment: Also in your `CInfo` class if you put a breakpoint on the lines which fetch the token, do they actually get the token ?

Comment: Tell you after trying

Comment: Bro it doesnot work i put sassion before sendAndRequestResponse() function

Comment: And added internet permission?

Comment: Yes I think a problem exist on api side

Comment: Probably try using Postman that will eliminate your code being the issue. https://www.postman.com/